# Getting HTML 5 Audio Control file location and updating src without using id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the file location as shown in the Javascript alert but without using the id selector and then update the corresponding src attribute.   I have tried all sort of Jquery selectors but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.   There may be an unlimited amount of audio controls on the form and not just 3 so that is why I don't want to pinpoint the file location by id.

```js
function uploadAudioFile(that) {

  // would like to get the file info shown in the alert below after a user upload an MP3 and selects the "Upload Audio File" button but without using an id tag.    
  
  var audio_file = $(that).parent().next("audio");
  alert(audio_file);
  var val = audio_file.val();
  alert(val);
 //to select source you can use .find(), to update source .attr()

 var source = audio_file.find("source").attr("src", "updatedsong.mp3") //phony song for demo purposes
 alert(source);

  // would also like to know the jquery for updating the src attribute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="media">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <label></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label>Artist</label>
      <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

      <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

      <div class="form-group-audio">

        <div class="audio-controls">

          <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
          <input id="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button" onclick="uploadAudioFile(this);" class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />
      </span>
          <audio id="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
            <source src="song1.mp3" />
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <label>Song</label>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Artist</label>
    <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

    <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

    <div class="form-group-audio">

      <div class="audio-controls">

        <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
        <input id="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button" onclick="uploadAudioFile(this);" class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />
      </span>
        <audio id="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
          <source src="song2.mp3" />
        </audio>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <label>Song</label>

  <div class="form-inline">
    <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Artist</label>
  <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

  <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

  <div class="form-group-audio">

    <div class="audio-controls">

      <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
      <input id="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button" onclick="uploadAudioFile(this);" class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />
      </span>
      <audio id="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
        <source src="song3.mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<label>Song</label>

<div class="form-inline">
  <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Did not initally notice duplicate `id`'s within `document`. Replaced duplicate `id`s `"audiofile"` , `"mplayer"` with `className` at `html`.

Substituted `.click()` for inline event attribute `onclick` at `.btn.btn-info` element, used `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` within `uploadAudioFile()`; add `oncanplaythrough` event listener using `.on()` for `<audio>` elements, replaced `<source>` element with setting `src` attribute at `audio` element at `change` event for `<input type="file">` element.

At `click` of `.btn.btn-info` element, call `click()` on `input type="file"` element for `Open File` dialog to be displayed at click of `input type="button"` element.

Call `alert()` with uploaded `File.name`, `File.type`.

Use `URL.createObjectURL()` on selected `File` object to convert to a `blob:` URL, `$(this).sliblings("audio")` selector within `handleFile` function, which references `<audio>` sibling of `<input type="file">` element, set `src` of `audio` element to `objectURL`, which should invoke `oncanplaythrough` handler, call `.play()` on `DOM` `<audio>` element to play uploaded audio file.

javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("audio").on("canplaythrough", function(event) {
      this.play();
    });

    function handleFile(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      // would like to get the file info shown in the alert below
      alert("name:" + file.name + " type:" + file.type);
      $(this).siblings("audio")
        // would also like to know the jquery for updating the src attribute
      .attr("src", src)
    }

    function uploadAudioFile(e) {
      //  after a user upload an MP3 and selects the 
      // "Upload Audio File" button but without using an id tag.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().siblings(":file").click();
    }
    $(".btn.btn-info").click(uploadAudioFile);
    $(":file").change(handleFile)
  })
</script>
```

html

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input type="button" 
       class="btn btn-info" 
       name="audio_search"  
       value="Upload Audio File" />
</span>
<audio id="mplayer" 
       class="player" 
       controls="controls" 
       preload="metadata">
<!-- <source src="" /> -->
```

---

You should be able to use `.parent()`, `.next()`

```
var audio_file = $(that).parent().next("audio");
var val = audio_file.val()
```

to select `source` you can use `.find()`, to update `source` `.attr()`

```
var source = audio_file.find("source").attr("src", /* new source */)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("audio").on("canplaythrough", function(event) {
      this.play();
    });

    function handleFile(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      // would like to get the file info shown in the alert below
      alert("name:" + file.name + " type:" + file.type);
      $(this).siblings("audio")
        // would also like to know the jquery for updating the src attribute
        .attr("src", src)
    }

    function uploadAudioFile(e) {
      //  after a user upload an MP3 and selects the 
      // "Upload Audio File" button but without using an id tag.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().siblings(":file").click();
    }
    $(".btn.btn-info").click(uploadAudioFile);
    $(":file").change(handleFile)
  })
</script>

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="media">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <label></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label>Artist</label>
      <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

      <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

      <div class="form-group-audio">

        <div class="audio-controls">

          <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
          <input class="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />
      </span>
          <audio class="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
            <!-- <source src="" /> -->
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <label>Song</label>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Artist</label>
    <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

    <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

    <div class="form-group-audio">

      <div class="audio-controls">

        <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
        <input class="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />      </span>
        <audio class="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
          <!-- <source src="" /> -->
        </audio>
      </div>

    </div>

    <label>Song</label>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Artist</label>
    <input name="album" class="form-control" size="64" type="text" value="" />

    <h3 class="customize-heading"></h3>

    <div class="form-group-audio">

      <div class="audio-controls">

        <label for="audiofile" class="tooltiper" title="NA">Upload audio File</label>
        <input class="audiofile" class="audiofile" accept=".mp3,.wav" name="audiofile" type="file" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
       <input type="button"

                                   class="btn btn-info" name="audio_search"  value="Upload Audio File" />

      </span>
        <audio class="mplayer" class="player" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
          <!-- <source src="" /> -->
        </audio>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <label>Song</label>

  <div class="form-inline">
    <input name="song" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.   I updated the code with this info.  It seems close and this is the sort of logic I was trying myself but I can't get it to work with at least with the html for in the example I provided.   I have seen elsewhere where people suggest using .get(0).files[0]; and that seems to return the actual file location when paid with an ID but I'm trying to do this without id's.

Comment: @celticsfan Must have mistaken requirement, here. Is expected result to upload file from `<input type="file">` to set as `src` of of `<audio>` element?

Comment: Yes.   That is exactly what I am looking for.   I probably didn't express it correctly in the original question.

Comment: Great answer!   Thanks a bunch.   Wow.   This is a little more code and cleanup of my original code than I thought would be necessary but it not only works, it makes sense and lets me focus in on the syntax that I need to learn.

Comment: I am new to posting to stackoverflow so my votes don't count for the time being but I have upvoted your answer as correct since from everything I can see and hear it is correct.   Thanks again.